# How to get NMinimize to work

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
f[t_] := Sin[t]*Cos[10*t]*(E^(-t/4) - E^(-t))
pt1 = {t  /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} & @NMaximize[{f[t], 0 < t < 10}, t]
pt2 = {t  /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} & @NMinimize[{f[t], 0 < t < 10}, t]
Plot[{f[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[ {pt1, pt2}]}]
```

I am not getting the minimum value of f[t] in the range 0 < t < 10. Any suggestion on how to get the correct minimum value?

Comment: In `NMaximize` and `NMinimize` use `Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", MaxIterations -> 500`.

Comment: In this case just replacing `NMaximize` and `NMinimize` with `Maximize` and `Minimize` works.

Answer (score 2):

```
NMinimize[{f[t], 0 < t < 10}, t, Method -> SimulatedAnnealing]
{-0.467368, {t -> 1.57162}}
```

Comment: If I change the function to f[t_] := Sin[10*t]*Cos[100*t]*(E^(-t/4) - E^(-t)), I don't seem to get the max and min using Method-> SimulatedAnnealing. I wonder how robust is the method?

Comment: @user11946 I suggest you take a look at the tutorial here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html

Comment: There is no method which will work 100% of the time, and in finite time.